# how to set the speed of a drone with dji sdk mobile?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am currently trying to create an app' that would set the speed of a drone at 1.8m/s so I wouldn't have to gauge the remote controler while the drone is flying (wether on a remote controler or on an app', it is not important as long as it works). I use DJI Mobile SDK 4.16 for my drones DJI M210 V2 or DJI Mavic 2 Enterprise Advanced. I'm not the best at developing apps unfortunatly and I don't really know this SDK.

I have tried to find some functions in the DJI Mobile SDK that would manage the drone's speed but they seem to be nowhere to be found. I may have found some functions to automate the missions with waypoints, or functions that get the engine's status but I did not find (or see), ... But no functions that would do what I'm looking for. I see the same problem within the offical documentation where I think any of the functions displayed there are for API, and I don't find many descriptions.

This project does not seem that complicated to code though.

Do you have any ideas of where such functions could be, or any tutorials, projects  or sample codes that would help me ?

Thank you